# VBA copy-function failing at random

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have written a function that copies charts from a excel workbook onto a premade powerpoint. Charts are defined by name in both the pp and workbook. For some reason i get the 1004 error when its tries to copy the chart from excel. This doesn't always happen at in the first call of the function, but seemingly at random times. Am i missing something?

```
Public Sub PlaceChart(pres, name, slide)
    Set PPTSlide = pres.Slides(slide)
    Set CurShape = PPTSlide.Shapes(name)
        h = CurShape.height
        w = CurShape.width
        t = CurShape.top
        l = CurShape.left
        CurShape.Delete
    Set CurChart = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(name)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        CurChart.Copy
        PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
    Set CurShape = PPTSlide.Shapes(name)
        CurShape.height = h
        CurShape.width = w
        CurShape.top = t
        CurShape.left = l
End Sub
```

The function finds a shape in the powerpoint, copies its dimensions and then deletes it. It then uses these dimensions resize the new chart once it's pasted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call the sub? Maybe add `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: `Call PlaceChart(myPresentation, name, 8)`

I tried and it doesn't work. How would it explain the call working sometimes?

Comment: At which code line does the error appear?

Comment: Is it filling memory due to the size of the charts copied?

Comment: The error appears at `CurChart.Copy`.

Comment: I don't think it's filling up memory, since it sometimes runs all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sub for the following

```
Public Sub PlaceChart(pres, name, slide)
    Set PPTSlide = pres.Slides(slide)
    Set CurShape = PPTSlide.Shapes(name)
        h = CurShape.height
        w = CurShape.width
        t = CurShape.top
        l = CurShape.left
        CurShape.Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(name).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(name).Copy
    PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
    Set CurShape = PPTSlide.Shapes(name)
        CurShape.height = h
        CurShape.width = w
        CurShape.top = t
        CurShape.left = l
End Sub
```

And it seems to be working consistently now.